# How I get to know that my app is exit from the recent apps of the device or not in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, lifecycle

I am new in Flutter. I am working on one of my demo Flutter app. I have created 3 screens (Login, Signup and Home) in my app. I am just navigating to the Home screen from the login screen. Now I want to check - Is my app is alive or closed? - by clearing the app from the recent apps in Android and IOS. I have checked **AppLifecycleState.detached** and also checked override method **dispose()** but these are not calling while user killed the app. 
Please help me how I come to know that my app got killed. Which method I need to use.

I have used *AppLifecycleState.paused* for other process. So I want any other way to handle it.

In native Android we can check this with the help of *onDestroy()* method and in iOS native app we can check it with the help of *applicationWillTerminate()* .

Which method I need to use for Flutter?

Please help me to fix it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -11, accepted):

I found one solution to detect if the app destroyed or exit. In flutter we have dispose() method. In my case the dispose() method was not called when app destroyed. So I just updated my dispose() method. See the below code.

```
 @mustCallSuper
  @protected
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose

    print('dispose called.............');
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: It does not print anything

Comment: This is a wrong answer. Dispose is a method triggered whenever the created object from the stateful widget is removed permanently from the widget tree but not when app is closed.

Comment: @Nazmul81 do you have any solution for this?

Comment: I also searched for the best solution. You can try with observer it may help sometime. @PrateekSharma

Answer (score 1):

Hey so first of all we have to understand few things. The `AppLifecycleState` is invoked by flutter engine when the app goes in background or comes to foreground.
When its getting killed, its an OS callback, so you will have to deal with both iOS and android natively.
For android when an app is killed, an intent is fired, which is known as [ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED). You can invoke a [broadcaster](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) when it happens like

```
public class RestartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action= intent.getAction();
}
```

Note this is a Java code so you might have to write kotlin version yourself. Now you can invoke your broadcaster from Androidmanifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".ReceiverTest">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Something similar is available for Apple where you can get a callback for [app termination](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate).